# Agora cloud recording S3 Integration

Tags: php, amazon-s3, agora.io

I have been trying to implement the Agora cloud recording functionality for a few days with some difficulty. The API documentation is difficult to work with, and using their POSTMAN collection implementation I was not able to get it working properly.
This is the payload sent to the /start/ endpoint, after joining the user to the channel via the web client:

```
{
   "cname":"$channel",
   "uid":"$uid" //unqiue user id that joins the channel,
   "clientRequest":{
      "recordingConfig":{
         "channelType":0,
         "maxIdleTime":15,
         "streamTypes":2,
         "transcodingConfig":{
            "width":640,
            "height":480,
            "fps":15,
            "bitrate":500,
            "backgroundColor":"#fff000"
         }
      },
      "recordingFileConfig":{
         "avFileType":[
            "hls",
            "mp4"
         ]
      },
      "storageConfig":{
         "accessKey":"$access",
         "secretKey":"$secret",
         "region":1, // US-EAST-2
         "bucket":"$bucketname",
         "vendor":1,
         "fileNamePrefix":[
            "recordings",
            "raw"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

After receiving the response I hit the /query/ endpoint, this returns:

```
{
   "resourceId": "$rid",
       "serverResponse": {
           "status": 6,
           "fileList": [],
           "fileListMode": "json",
           "sliceStartTime": 0
       }
}
```

Sometimes it gives me:

```
{
    "resourceId": "$rid",
    "sid": "$sid",
    "code": 404
}
```

When I hit the /stop/ endpoint It returns with this:

```
{
    "resourceId": "$rid",
    "code": 404,
    "serverResponse": {
        "command": "StopCloudRecorder",
        "payload": {
            "message": "Failed to find worker."
        },
        "subscribeModeBitmask": 1,
        "vid": "$vid"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide RTC token in "clientRequest" like docs said so: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_start?platform=RESTful

Comment: My last implementation after this did send a payload with the token attached but it is still the same thing. Will have a look again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because the Bucket region is hardcoded as `region: 1` but this might not be right region for your bucket

```json
      "storageConfig":{
         "accessKey":"$access",
         "secretKey":"$secret",
         "region":1, // US-EAST-2 <--- Change This
         "bucket":"$bucketname",
         "vendor":1,
         "fileNamePrefix":[
            "recordings",
            "raw"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That is the correct region, I checked it over multiple times!

Comment: Is the bitrate correct?

Comment: Just found the table with the bitrate values, trying it now